# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, pointcut

I got the following advice :-

```
@Before(value="@annotation(loggable)", argNames="joinPoint, loggable")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, Loggable loggable) {
        Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint
                .getSignature();
        Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        RequestMapping myAnnotation = method
                .getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint
                .getSignature();
        String[] argNames = codeSignature.getParameterNames();
        logger.info(".....");

    }
```

in Class LoggerAspect:

```
package net.prcins.esales.web.aspects;



import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import net.prcins.esales.aspect.IRequestLogger;
import net.prcins.esales.log.annotation.Loggable;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect implements IRequestLogger{

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggerAspect");

    long startTime;

    //@Before(value = "execution(* net.prcins.esales.web.controller..*(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)", argNames="joinPoint, loggable")

    @Before(value="@annotation(net.prcins.esales.log.annotation.Loggable)", argNames="joinPoint, loggable")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, Loggable loggable) {
        Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint
                .getSignature();
        Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        RequestMapping myAnnotation = method
                .getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint
                .getSignature();
        String[] argNames = codeSignature.getParameterNames();
        logger.info(
                "Entering Method [{}] RequestMapping:[{}] QuoteInformation:[{}]",
                new Object[] {
                        methodName,
                        constructRequestMappingString(method
                                .getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class)),
                        arguments(argNames, args) });

    }


    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) {

        Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        if (joinPoint.getSignature() instanceof MethodSignature) {

            MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
            Class<?> returnType = signature.getReturnType();

            if ("void".equalsIgnoreCase(returnType.getName())) {
                logger.debug("  <<<==== Leaving {} " , new Object[] { methodName});
                return;
            }
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.debug( " <<<==== Leaving {} in {} ms returnValue: {}", new Object[] {methodName,(startTime-endTime),constructArgumentsString(clazz, returnValue)}  );

    }


    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint,  Throwable throwable) {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        logger.error(" Exception in method:"+methodName, throwable);

    }

    private String constructArgumentsString(Class<?> clazz, Object... arguments) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (Object object : arguments) {
            if (object instanceof byte[]) {
                //do nothig
            }else {
                buffer.append(object);
                buffer.append(", ");
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }


    private String constructRequestMappingString(RequestMapping myAnnotation) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String requestURL : myAnnotation.value()) {
            buffer.append(requestURL);
        }
        for (RequestMethod requestMethod : myAnnotation.method()) {
            buffer.append(", ");
            buffer.append(requestMethod.name().toString());
        }
        return buffer.toString();

    }

    private String arguments(String[] argNames, Object[] arguments) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if ("model".equalsIgnoreCase(argNames[i])) {
                String modelInfo = arguments[i].toString();
                String[] tokens = modelInfo.split(", ");
                for (String token : tokens) {
                    if (token.startsWith("quoteNumber")) {
                        return token;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

and this Annotation:

```
package net.prcins.esales.log.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import net.prcins.esales.log.LogLevel;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {

    LogLevel value();
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring/esales-web-context.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0' while setting bean property 'cacheOperationSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0' while setting bean property 'cacheOperationSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:852)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:210)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 53 more
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /esales-ui-web threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:210)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:852)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\MylesERemindersEnterprise.xml
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:MylesERemindersEnterprise' did not find a matching property.
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\MylesERemindersWeb.xml
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:MylesERemindersWeb' did not find a matching property.
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 9, 2014 11:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9413 ms
```

I get the error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: loggable

Why is Loggable no Annotation? It is marked with @interface

Comment: I saw the question but the solution to include the annotation as method parameter didn't work for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574348/error-type-referred-to-is-not-an-annotation-type

Comment: Are you using the same `Loggable`?

Comment: Yes, using the same Loggable

Comment: What happens if you capitalize `loggable`?

Comment: @chrylis you mean like that : 
@Before(value="@annotation(Loggable)", argNames="joinPoint, loggable")

Comment: @chrylis Tried the above change, got the same error.

Comment: would this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574348/error-type-referred-to-is-not-an-annotation-type

Comment: @CamilleDouine this doesn't work as I have already included the loggable annotation as my method argument. Added that as the first thing in the above comments.

Comment: And have you tried the FQN instead of the simple name?

Comment: @chrylis Tried the below change but still no luck
@Before(value="@annotation(loggable)", argNames="JoinPoint, Loggable")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, net.prcins.esales.log.annotation.Loggable loggable) {

Comment: Show the entire file with your advice method. You haven't shown the `import` for `Loggable`.

Comment: @chrylis Tried the FQN name for the Loggable annotation and also included the class in question.

Comment: Package declaration for `Loggable`?

Comment: @chrylis included the package declaration for Loggable

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis updated the question with stacktrace

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are showing. Consider giving us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can do exactly what you are doing. Cut out all the irrelevant business logic though.

Comment: At this point, based on that stack trace, it looks like you have stale binaries (it's still seeing a **type** named `loggable`).

Comment: @chrylis You are very much correct, it was pointing to stale binaries. It worked after I updated the dependencies and pointed to the annotation it is referring to. Thanks!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for looking into it. The problem got resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue by refreshing and updating the dependencies. Somewhere it was not referring to the correct `Loggable` annotation. Just made sure that it is pointing to the annotation, it is referring to.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I have reimport the maven dependencies and it worked well @Sanjeev